# Android Lollipop - How to make Notifications show on the Notification Drawer but not on the Status Bar?

Tags: android, android-notifications

On my HTC One M7, Android 5.0.2, HTC Sense 6.0, there are some notifications that are showing on the Notification Drawer, but not on the Status bar (and not on the Lock Screen). For example, Google Now weather info and Facebook Messenger "Chat heads active."

They can be ongoing or one-time.

I couldn't find any documentation on this. How do I create such notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [PRIORITY_MIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#PRIORITY_MIN) with [setPriority()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setPriority(int)) as explained in the [notifications design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#correctly_set_and_manage_notification_priority):

> MIN: Use for contextual or background information such as weather information or contextual location information. **Minimum-priority notifications do not appear in the status bar.** The user discovers them on expanding the notification shade.

Answer (score 0):

Using NotificationCompat.Builder:

```
mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
```